# Memory usage for an Elixir utility script that filters content from stdin to sdout

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to write a simple elixir utility script that takes some text as input from STDIN (i.e. a PostgreSQL dump), filters that text and outputs it to STDOUT to be used by subsequent commands:

`pg_restore db-backup/big_dump.psql.gz | db_trimmer.exs | psql ...`

My first version of the script would be to remove all the lines of the dump that copy the data (starts with `COPY` and ends with `\.`):

```
COPY xx_table ... FROM stdin
4       33380   \N      \N
4       33380   \N      \N
\.
```

My goal is to be in control with the memory used by that script because the dump can be very big. So I've started using the Elixir `Stream` module and functions. I've ended up with a first implementation using `IO.stream` and `Stream.transform`:

```
IO.stream(:stdio, :line)
|> Stream.transform(false, fn line, skipping ->
  cond do
    !skipping && String.starts_with?(line, "COPY") -> {[{true, line}], true}
    skipping && line == "\\.\n" -> {[{true, line}], false}
    true -> {[{skipping, line}], skipping}
  end
end)
|> Stream.filter(fn {skipping, _} -> !skipping end)
|> Stream.map(fn {_, line} -> line end)
|> Stream.into(IO.stream(:stdio, :line))
|> Stream.run()
```

But when I run this script on a big dump I notice that first the process memory starts to grow a lot and then stabilizes. But then the process virtual memory continues to grow...

And I'm noticing the same behaviour with an even simpler script:

```
IO.stream(:stdio, :line)
|> Stream.into(IO.stream(:stdio, :line))
|> Stream.run()
```

I'm wondering how can I control the memory usage of that script (buffer, number of lines in memory)? Do you have suggestions on how to implement this logic in a better way? Maybe I should drop my idea of using STDIN and STDOUT and do all the pipeline in Elixir?

Answer (score 0):

maybe give [Flow](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html) a try? You can use [this trick](https://howdoicomputer.ghost.io/including-a-dependency-in-an-elixir-script/) to use a dependency in a script file.